# Best method to store and retrieve files with metadata

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, machine-learning, search-engine

Let's say I have the list of the files. They have metadata, for example tags like `php, html, css` or `maths, homeworks` etc. What is the best way to retrieve such files? Are `MATCH..AGAINST` or `LIKE('%user_post_tag%')` the only solutions? Are there any machine learning techniques which can be applied here, so if user opens the same file often, it will rank better and be on the top of the list after the search is done? How the search should be done (are there any popular techniques?) if we have a file storage website and the most important thing is having a good search?

P.S. User would type in the search something like `give me a file with math homeworks`, or maybe just `math homeworks`.

Answer (score 1):

You are planning to use CSV in a database.
This is always a bad idea.

Use a tag table like this:

```
Table tag
  id primary key integer auto_increment
  tag char(10) unique key
```

With a n-to-n link table

```
Table tag_link
  tag_id integer
  article_id integer
  primary key (article_id, tag_id)
```

Then you have a subject table

```
Table article
  id integer primary key auto_increment
  .....
```

Now you can look for all articles with a tag using the following query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.header, a.body 
FROM tag t
INNER JOIN tag_link tl ON (t.id = tl.tag_id)
INNER JOIN article a ON (a.id = tl.tag_id)
WHERE t.tag = 'search-engine'
```

This is the fastest way and in fact it's the method that stackoverflow itself uses.

See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/161093